# Could have C++20 templated lambdas be specified to deduce the type nested inside an argument?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

C++20 lambdas get a new feature(paper p0428r2.), you can specify `<typename T>` as in normal function...
Reading that paper I noticed one example:

```
auto f = []<typenameT>(std::vector<T> vector) { /* ... */ };
```

That got me thinking:

Why does langage not "figure out" that T is a type(since std::vector is a template that expects type parameter inside `<>`).

```
auto f = [](std::vector<T> vector) { /* T deduced ... */ };
```

Is there a technical limitation preventing this, or is the use case too obscure/rare to warrant a language rule for it?

Comment: `T` can be a type you made yourself.  Do you want it to error or silently compile?  Thus the "verbose" syntax to make it clear you want a template.

Comment: Note: C++ as a language is not in the habit of having the mere *use* of an identifier that happens to not identify anything in a particular context implicitly become a declaration. If you want an identifier to mean something, you have to declare it to have that meaning with some syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a technical limitation preventing this, or is the use case too obscure/rare to warrant a language rule for it?

Yes, there is a <s>technical</s> limitation preventing this. That code *already has a meaning*.

```
struct T { int i; };
auto f = [](std::vector<T> vector) { /* T not actually deduced */ };
```

Templates are very different from non-templates (see [P1392](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p1392r0.html) for a thorough treatment). One of the reasons that the concepts "terse" syntax is spelled `concept auto x` instead of just `concept x` is because there was a strong desire by many people that the same syntax shouldn't mean wildly different things based on the *kind* of name used.

Such a language feature would lead to the same syntax meaning wildly different things based on *whether* the name were found at all - which seems like it would be incredibly difficult to understand the code. Even worse, it'd lead to cases where the intent of the author was that this lambda actually be a template and then sometime later it just becomes either a non-template through incidental addition of a name or just ill-formed if the name that was incidentally introduced named a variable (i.e. `int T;`)

---

The Concepts TS had a different syntax for this, which was:

```
auto f = [](std::vector<auto> vector) { /* deduced, but no name */ };
```

It seems likely that this Concepts TS feature will be proposed for C++23, since it would certainly be useful for the same reason that I would still write `[](auto x){}` in many places instead of `[]<class T>(T x){}`.

Comment: That's not a technical limitation, so long as you permit cases where `T` is already a valid identifier to have their old meaning. There is no technical reason why you can't do this; there is only good language design reasons. Like not overloading syntaxes to mean different things based on arbitrary context.

Comment: @NicolBolas Fair point. I guess it is _technically_ implementable.

Comment: On the subject of “very different”: we wrote a [paper](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p1392r0.html).